# Android, get values from Map to an Object, with given class

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I get my data from Firestore, and save them to a Map string, object.
The data looks like this:

```
[auto-generated key]
    fieldname: value
    fieldname: value
...
```

There can be any number of fields, they can be named to anything and store numbers/text/timestamps.
I get them into a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();

for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {            
    myMap.put(document.getId(), document.getData());
}
```

**What I wanna do**:
I have a class for the data, I wanna store them in a List, with this type.

```
public class DemoData {
    public String autoId;
    public List<String> fieldNames;
    public List<Object> values;

    public DemoData() {}
}
```

So here's **the code I have now**:
I can get a list of keys, and a list of fieldname-value pairs.

```
List<String> k = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> v = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    k.add(entry.getKey());
    v.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

(Looks like):
[image]

How can i go over in the List "v", each item's each fieldname-value pair and save them into two separate lists. (and then form DemoData object from them).

So a DemoData object would look like this:

```
autoId: "YbWQh..."
fieldNames: ["default", "entity_name", "Datum", "fav"...]
values: [false,"Fontos datumok", Timestamp..., false...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` has a constructor that accepts any data structure that implements `Collection` interface. `Map` has methods which return all the keys and values at once in a `Set` which implements `Collection` interface. You can use them to get the data in the format you want.

This should work

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    DemoData demoData = new DemoData();
    demoData.fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(); // line# 1
    demoData.values = new ArrayList<>(); //line# 2
    demoData.autoId = k.get(i).toString();
    HashMap m = v.get(i);
    demoData.fieldNames.addAll(m.keySet());
    demoData.values.addAll(m.values());
}
```

Ideally, you should remove line# 1 and 2 from my code and move this to the constructor of class `DemoData`.

Comment: I already saved map.values to "v", and it stores the keys (field names), and values in pairs, what I wanna do is split them in two. map.keyset gives me back the auto generated id-s, which are saved to "k"

Comment: I know. I am not using `map` variable of your code. I am only using `k` and `v`. Please try the code, you will get a new demoData object in each iteration.

Comment: Use my code after the for loop which add data in k and v

Comment: it dies here:  demoData.fieldnames.addAll(m.keySet()); with this error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.addAll(java.util.Collection)' on a null object reference. Plus it asked me to do this convertion: Map m = (Map) v.get(i);

Comment: Please try now.